# Custom route configuration with Silex

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml, silex

I know that the basis of Silex approach in which all the application logic in a single file. But my application will be possible to have more than twenty controllers. So I want to have a handy map to manage the router.

My question is to search for solutions in which I would be able to make a router to a separate file. In the best case, the file must be of YAML type:

```
# config/routing.yml

_home:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: MyProject\Controller\MyController::index }
```

But the native is also a good case (*for me*):

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add(
    'home',
    new Route('/', array('controller' => 'MyProject\Controller\MyController::index')
));

return $routes;
```

Problem of the second case is that I have to use the **match()** function for each rule of routing. It is not at all clear.

What are the ways to solve this issue? The condition is that I want to use the existing API Silex or components of Symfony2.

*Small note*:

I don't use a **ControllerProviderInterface** for my Controller classes. This is an independent classes.

Comment: When you have that much controllers, that's a sign you should be using the full-stack framework instead of silex.

Comment: @maerlyn silex is a micro framework, that doesn't mean it shouldn't be used for big projects. That does mean that you need to make your own decisions on how to organize your project. See this for more information: https://igor.io/2012/11/09/scaling-silex.html

Comment: @WouterJ I agree and I have used silex for big projects too, I just wanted the OP to consider that alternative as well.

Comment: Hey @Stmol, have you see my answer? I had the exact same requirement as you, figured it out in the simplest way possible :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the basis of Silex is not that you put everything in one file. The basis of Silex is that you create your own 'framework', your own way of organizing applications.

> "Use silex if you are comfortable with making all of your own architecture decisions and full stack Symfony2 if not."
>   -- Dustin Whittle

Read more about this in [this blogpost](https://igor.io/2012/11/09/scaling-silex.html), created by the creator of Silex.

---

#### How to solve your problem

What you basically want is to parse a Yaml file and get the `pattern` and `defaults._controller` settings from each route that is parsed.

To parse a Yaml file, you can use [the Yaml Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) of Symfony2. You get an array back which you can use to add the route to Silex:

```php
// parse the yaml file
$routes = ...;
$app = new Silex\Application();

foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $app->match($route['pattern'], $route['defaults']['_controller']);
}

// ...
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 5):

I thought I'd add my method here as, although others may work, there isn't really a simple solution. Adding `FileLocator` / `YamlFileLoader` adds a load of bulk that I don't want in my application just to read / parse a yaml file.

**Composer**

First, you're going to need to include the relevant files. The symfony YAML component, and a really simple and useful [config service provider](https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider) by [someone who actively works on Silex](https://github.com/igorw).

```
"require": {
    "symfony/yaml": "~2.3",
    "igorw/config-service-provider": "1.2.*"
}
```

**File**

Let's say that your routes file looks like this (`routes.yml`):

```
config.routes:
  dashboard:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: 'IndexController::indexAction' }
    method:   GET
```

**Registration**

Individually register each yaml file. The first key in the file is the name it will be available under your `$app` variable (handled by the pimple service locator).

```
$this->register(new ConfigServiceProvider(__DIR__."/../config/services.yml"));
$this->register(new ConfigServiceProvider(__DIR__."/../config/routes.yml"));
// any more yaml files you like
```

**Routes**

You can get these routes using the following:

```
$routes = $app['config.routes']; // See the first key in the yaml file for this name
foreach ($routes as $name => $route)
{
    $app->match($route['pattern'], $route['defaults']['_controller'])->bind($name)->method(isset($route['method'])?$route['method']:'GET');    
}
```

`->bind()` allows you to 'name' your urls to be used within twig, for example.
`->method()` allows you to specify POST | GET. You'll note that I defaulted it to 'GET' with a ternary there if the route doesn't specify a method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's how I solved it.

This method is part of my application and called before **run()**:

```
# /src/Application.php

...

protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $locator = new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/config');
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader($locator);

    $this['routes'] = $loader->load('routes.yml');
}
```

Application class is my own and it extends Silex\Application.

Configuration file:

```
# /src/config/routes.yml
home:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: '\MyDemoSite\Controllers\DefaultController::indexAction' }
```

It works fine for me!

**UPD**:

I think this is the right option to add collections:

```
$this['routes']->addCollection($loader->load('routes.yml'));
```

More flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `routes` service (which is a `RouteCollection`), and load a YAML file with `FileLocator` and `YamlFileLoader`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$app->extend('routes', function($routeCollection) {

    $locator    = new FileLocator([__DIR__ . '/../config']);
    $loader     = new YamlFileLoader($locator);
    $collection = $loader->load('routes.yml');

    $routeCollection->addCollection($collection);

    return $routeCollection;

});
```

You will need `symfony/config` and `symfony/yaml` dependencies though.